# Get data joining two table in room having same column id

Tags: android, spring-boot, orm, android-sqlite, android-room

Hi I am using two table student and student_address having common column id as uid in both table(that can't be changed in any condition)

I am using class StudentAndAddress as

```
public class StudentAndAddress{

    @Embedded
    private Student student;

    @Embedded(prefix = "type_")
    private StudentAddress studentAddress;

    public Address getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public StudentAddress getStudentAddress() {
        return studentAddress;
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(StudentAddress studentAddress) {
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

}
```

and query i am using as:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM student  INNER JOIN student_address ON student.uid == student_address.address_uid and address_link.linkto_type==:linkToType")
LiveData<List<StudentAndAddress>> getStudentAndAddress(String linkToType);
```

I am getting value of first table but not getting value of second table.
In database both table are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In room we need to solve this type of queries using relation

```
public class StudentAndAddress{

    @Embedded
    private StudentAddress studentAddress;


    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "address_uid",
            entityColumn = "uid",
            entity = Student.class
    )
    private Student student;


    public Address getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public StudentAddress getStudentAddress() {
        return studentAddress;
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(StudentAddress studentAddress) {
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

}
```

and query we need to write is:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM student_address WHERE linkto_type==:linkToType")
LiveData<List<StudentAndAddress>> getStudentAndAddress(String linkToType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, source of your problem is prefix, that you gave to your @Embedded:

```
@Embedded(prefix = "type_")
private StudentAddress studentAddress;
```

With that Room can't match fields names in query result and fields in your class StudentAndAddress. You have to either get rid of the prefix (then filelds' names would be equal) or change aliases in your query for the Address table (to add your prefix to them) - something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT student.*,addresses.[field1] as type_[field1], adsresses.address_uid as type_address_uid, ... FROM student  INNER JOIN student_address as addresses ..."
```